# Network conf - ever time must set ifconfig

Tags: linux, networking, boot, ifconfig

I need to autoconfigure network.
Network Manager is removed because I need lightweight system.

After system starts networks doesn't work.

```
#service networking status
networking stop/waiting

#service networking start  
networking stop/waiting
```

/etc/network/interfaces (eth1 isn't mistake)

```
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.2.8
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.2.1
dns-server 8.8.8.8
```

But if i type

```
#ifconfig eth1 192.168.2.8/24
#route add default gw 192.168.2.1
```

networking works

Why it doesn't configure interface eth1 automaticaly after boot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This assumes that you are running Mint, and that Mint didn't change anything from Debian on this matter)

You need an auto line:

```
auto eth1
```

Otherwise, the interface will not be handled by the `init.d/networking` script.

This way, the interface is started when `networking` is started, reconfigured if `networking` is reloaded/restarted and stopped when `networking` is stopped.

Alternatively, for hotplugged devices, you can use :

```
allow-hotplug eth1
```

This way, the device will be configured when it is plugged and unconfigured when unplugged. If the device is already plugged at boot, `networking` will start it, but will not touch it when `networking` is stopped/restarted/reloaded

Oh, and by the way, `ifconfig` is deprecated. I hope that your `ìfupdown` package is recent enough to use `ip` (from the `iproute2` package) instead.